# IntelliJ refactoring to inline redundant data class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Is there a sequence of IntelliJ automated refactoring's that will get rid of the superfluous class Foo?

Before refactoring:

```java
  public static class Foo {
    private final String s;
    public Foo(String s) {
      this.s = s;
    }

    public String getS() {
      return s;
    }
  }

  private static void run() {
    Foo f = new Foo("blah");
    f.getS().length();
    f.getS().getBytes();

    Foo f2 = new Foo("blahg");
    f2.getS().length();
    f2.getS().getBytes();
  }
```

After refactoring:

```java
  private static void run() {
    String f = "blah";
    f.length();
    f.getBytes();

    String f2 = new "blahg";
    f2.length();
    f2.getBytes();
  }
```

Reason for an automated refactoring in my specific case is the real life Foo is used a few thousand times. But I'm also just interested. It's pretty easy to get a proxy object to the state of Foo using other automated steps, but I just can't figure out how to go the last little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how this would work in a more generic setting, but I would:

- Refactor `Foo` to change the name of `getS` to something very distinct e.g. `XXXXXXXXX`
- String replace `.XXXXXXXXX()` with an empty string
- Regex stringn replace `Foo (\w+) = new Foo\("(\w+)"\);` with `String $1 = "$2"`;

This will deal with everything in the `run` method. Now you just need to manually delete `Foo`, which while it's not an is not a IntelliJ refactoring, it would only need to be done in one place so might be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

A safer way to do this would be to use structural replace

- search for structural replace in the menu
- type `$Instance$.getS().$MethodCall$($Parameter$)` in the search box
- add a filter on $Instance$ to only be instances of Foo
- replace with: `$Instance$.getS().$MethodCall$($Parameter$)`
- After this you could continue with structural replace and find all instances, and replace them but it's easier to just run `Migrate` and create a custom type map from class `Foo` to 'String`
- if you wanted to use structural replace again you can use something like this for the find and replace

  - `Foo $name$ = new Foo($Parameter$);`
  - `String $name$ = $Parameter$;`